# Remove all chars between two strings with ABAP

Tags: xml, abap

I have a string with a XML in ABAP. I want to delete entire XML elements from begin tag to end tag. This is an example of XML stored in a string:

```
<ext:UBLExtensions/>
<Periodo FechaIngreso="2012-05-22"
         FechaLiquidacionInicio="2021-09-01"
         FechaLiquidacionFin="2021-09-30"
         TiempoLaborado="3369" 
         FechaGen="2022-01-25"/>
<NumeroSecuenciaXML CodigoTrabajador="10000001"
                    Prefijo="XYZW"
                    Consecutivo="959"
                    Numero="XYZW959"/>
<LugarGeneracionXML Pais="CO"
                    DepartamentoEstado="11"
                    MunicipioCiudad="11001"
                    Idioma="es"/>
<ProveedorXML RazonSocial="CORPORATION S.A.S"
              NIT="999888777"
              DV="7"
              SoftwareID="9999999-db88-7777-6666-25354825d26"
              SoftwareSC="56db49152e32874056e92c693b11013a31bc16d5419ab5561b2acd6d32b2a79985b3"/>
<CodigoQR>https://catalogo-vpfe-hab.nexo.com/document/searchqr?documentkey=b0c36d9f1a9c50fe4fecc5f812ff077c5a0f11da834c345b4881d762b7643b1fb744be9ecc6ebfaf64d7a84ba</CodigoQR>
<InformacionGeneral Version="V1.0: Documento Soporte de Pago de Nómina Electrónica"
                    Ambiente="2"
                    TipoXML="102"
                    CUNE="b0c36d9f1a9c50fe4fecc4881d762b7643b1fb744be9ecc6ebfaf64d7a84ba"
                    EncripCUNE="1234"
                    FechaGen="2022-01-25"
                    HoraGen="18:06:22-05:00"
                    PeriodoNomina="5"
                    TipoMoneda="COP"/>
```

Then, I want to delete

- the element `ProveedorXML` from begin tag to close tag: `<ProveedorXML  RazonSocial="...... 5b3"/>`
- and the element `CodigoQR` from begin tag to end tag: `<CodigoQR>htt......4ba</CodigoQR>`

I tried with find the first position of the begin tag and find the position of the end tag, then assign the substring between these 2 positions (with `SY-FDPOS`) but when I try to replace this substring in the string with stored XML (with `REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES`), I get a `SY-SUBRC` = 4 and the string with XML stored has not changed.

How can I use a different approach?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the [`replace()`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abenreplace_functions.htm) built-in function (see [built-in functions](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/11/30/reminder-abap-built-in-functions/)) with an appropriate RegEx and replace with `''` or parse the XML using [iXML library](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenabap_ixml_lib.htm) and remove the node there. As I am no longer an ABAP dev and do not have a SAP system available I can't write/ test that for you but those two ideas should work.

Comment: Please provide the code so that we fix your bug. Please post a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).